# Why does ITaskScheduler throw an exception when creating a task containing a dot in the name?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm trying to use the `ITaskScheduler` interface to create a scheduled task, using the C# wrapper from [PInvoke.Net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/ITaskScheduler.html).

I called the `Activate` method passing in the task name. It seems to work for certain task names and not others. For instance:

```
TaskName OK  
TaskName.1 Fails with: "Value does not fall within the expected range."  
TaskName.123 same error as above  
TaskName.1234 OK!
```

So basically if the name ends with a period followed by `<= 3`, it fails. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that since it's a virtual file the file extension is being limited to three letters. If you look at the list (in c:\windows\tasks) you will see that the tasks there all have .job extensions. I suggest doing the same until you have something that definitely works, then play with the extension.